# add conditional to filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ngtable

I am using Angular `ng-table` with filtering for a test prep platform. I am storing quiz results as `0 or 1` per question in DB, but need to show them as `Correct` or `Incorrect` to user.

I am able to do this with `{{q.result == 1 ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect'}}`

But this also needs to apply to filtering, meaning, the user should be able to type "Correct" and filter all questions with q.result = 1.

```
<tr ng-repeat="q in $data">
    <td title="'Correct/Incorrect'" filter="{ result: 'text'}" sortable="'q.result'" ng-class="{correct: q.result == 1, incorrect: q.result == 0}">
        {{q.result == 1 ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect'}}
    </td>
```

I've tried changing `filter="{ result: 'text'}` to follow the ternary convention above, but it does not work.

`filter="{(result == 1 ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect') : 'text'}"` gives error:

```
Syntax Error: Token '(' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{(result == 1 ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect') : 'text'}] starting at [(result == 1 ? 'Correct' : 'Incorrect') : 'text'}].
```

---

I am using a directive:

```
angular
    .module('DDE')
    .directive('results',['$rootScope', 'NgTableParams', function ($rootScope, NgTableParams) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {},
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/html/directives/results.html',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){
                scope.questions = [];
                /*
                    If user took a new test, show results
                 */
                scope.$on('show-results', function(event, args) {
                    scope.setData(args);
                });

                /*
                    Set question data
                 */
                scope.setData = function (args) {
                    console.log(args);
                    scope.questions = args;
                    scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { dataset: args});
                };
            }
        }
}]);
```

Console.logging `args` gives:

[image]

Comment: Can you include the part where you create the table in your controller?

Comment: @AlonEitan see above, it's a directive

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of this module is pretty crappy, this is how I sort and filter the table

```
scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, { 
    total: args.length,
    data: args,
    getData: function ( $defer, params ) {
        var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter( 'filter' )( scope.questions, params.filter() ) : scope.questions;
        orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter( 'orderBy' )( orderedData, params.orderBy() ) : orderedData;
        params.total( orderedData.length );
        $defer.resolve( orderedData );
    }
});
```

And you need to set the filter using `filter="{ result: 'text'}`, and also inject `$filter` into your directive.